# Angular - How to make a button on click with a function that is not on the component?

Tags: angular, function, button

So, I have a function called functionSave(). It is in the functionSave.ts file. I wanted to call it on my-component.html. They're both on the same folder. Is it possible to call it?

Comment: `import {functionSave } from './functionSave.ts'` and use it as `functionSave()`. in functionSave.ts the function have to be marked as export

Answer (score 0):

It is possible, just import it like so:

My `functionSave.ts` file.

```js
export function doSomething(value: any): any {
         // do something
        }
```

my component class:

```js
// import your function from functionSave
import { doSomething } from './functionSave';

@Component({})
class MyComponent {

  // save it in the component class
  public doSomething = doSomething;

}
```

And finally call it in the template:

```html
 <element (click)="doSomething()"></element>
```